# Parsing Data File's Lines by Delimiter Instead of EOL

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

I'm trying to parse a large text file (600MB) of raw data which I have no control on its format.

The problem is that the end of line is not placed well:

```
head -1 filename | wc -w
```

Produces a count of ~1.2K words per line. My target lines are are delimited by the \x06 character.

How can I re-organize the lines so that each one would end/start with ^F (\x06)? I've read many sed tutorials, but none mentioned this kind of a process...

`^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86    USER_INPUT 0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86  USER_INPUT 0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86  USER_INPUT 0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86   USER_INPUT    0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86  USER_INPUT 0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86    USER_INPUT   0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86    USER_INPUT   0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86    USER_INPUT   0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86    USER_INPUT   0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86    USER_INPUT   0`  `ID=34586238477^F1990451178631     E04:19:03.86    USER_INPUT   0`

What's the best way to do this by sed or similar tools?

Answer (score 2):

`awk` allows you to use a record separator other than newline. You can use it as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS=RS="\x06" } ...' input-file
```

Where ... is whatever you want to do with the data.

Comment: +1.  don't forget to set ORS too.

Comment: @cas Right. In most cases that would be necessary, too.